# My LG LEON battery dead?

Tags: battery, charging, lg, t-mobile

I was charging my LG LEON and it suddenly turned off with a 0 percentage of battery, then when i tried connecting it to the charger it didn't wanna charge. I tried with five different chargers and plugs but it still doesn't wanna charge.  My company is T-Mobile, i called and they told me to take the battery out for 10-15 seconds and to put it on again to see what happens, but it did not work. What should i do?

Comment: What does your screen display when you plug the charger in.

Comment: it does not display anything.. but when take the charger off and i try to turn it on it says 0 percentage of battery.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that could be at fault here.

1. The battery as been damaged or has simply reached the end of its usable life. You can bringing it to a professional to be replaced if it is internal or buy a replacement and put it in youeslef if it is removable.
2. More probable based on your description, the battery charger inside the phone has broken. Inside (almost) all electronics, there is a separate chip to control the charging cycle. This chip can break just like any other piece of your phone, which makes the phone unable to charge the battery and, depending on the internals, unable to report the correct battery percentage. Your battery may have been almost dead when it suddenly shut off. I had a Dell laptop reach its final day like this, so it isn't as ludicrous as you'd imagine. If this is the case, the phone is beyond reasonable repair and will have to be replaced.

If the battery is easily replaceable, do that first. If that doesn't help, your phone is done.